# How to create simple switch toggle to switch between dark theme and light theme in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, darkmode

I am creating a simple switch component that is if turned on the theme of the app will be light otherwise it would be dark.

Here is what i tried but it is not working. How can i make the toggle switch the theme of the whole app?

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Switch, Appearance } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);

  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);
  const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme();
  if (colorScheme === 'dark') {
    
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Switch
        style={{marginBottom:500, marginLeft:150}}
        trackColor={{ false: "light", true: "dark" }}
        thumbColor={isEnabled ? colorScheme == 'light' : colorScheme == 'dark'}
        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
        onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
        value={isEnabled}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`react-native-appearance-control`](https://github.com/72days/react-native-appearance-control). The Appearance API in react-native is read-only, but `react-native-appearance-control` provides methods for changing the underlying Color Scheme value for your app.

e.g.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Text, View, Switch, Appearance } from 'react-native';
import { setAppearanceLight, setAppearanceDark } from 'react-native-appearance-control';
        
export default function App() {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(Appearance.getColorScheme() === 'dark');       
  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);
    
  useEffect(()=>{
    if (isEnabled) {
      setAppearanceDark();
    } else {
      setAppearanceLight();
    }
  }, [isEnabled])

  return (
    <View>
      ...
      <Switch
        ...
        onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
        value={isEnabled}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use useEffect here.

```js
        import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
        import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
        import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Switch, Appearance } from 'react-native';
        
        export default function App() {
          const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
        
          const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);
    
          // add this
          useEffect(()=>{
            const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme();
              if (colorScheme === 'dark') {
                 setIsEnabled(true); // true means dark
              }else{
                 setIsEnabled(false); // false means light
              }
          },[])
    
          return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <StatusBar style="auto" />
              <Switch
                style={{marginBottom:500, marginLeft:150}}
                trackColor={{ false: "light", true: "dark" }}
                thumbColor={isEnabled ? colorScheme == 'light' : colorScheme == 'dark'}
                ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
                onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
                value={isEnabled}
              />
            </View>
          );
        }
```

Comment: its still not chaning the theme of the app to either dark or light, how can i make it if it is enabled its dark if it is not enabled it is light theme and so on

Comment: You can change how your app looks based on dark mode or light mode. But from what I'm aware of you can't change that part of the user settings from your app. So you will need to add styling that changes the appearance of your app based on if `isEnabled` is true or false

Comment: Yes @carlosdafield is right, you need to add styling based on `isEnabled` is true or false

Comment: @carlosdafield how can i do that?

Comment: Post another question I'll answer there. Sorry just the way stack overflow works

Comment: @carlosdafield but thats what i asked in this question specifically. "How to create simple switch toggle to switch between dark theme and light theme in react native". although your answer is appreciated, you didnt give me post a solution different than my question. my question already achieves what you posted.