# Change colors of the whole app in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, themes, darkmode

I want to enable dark mode in react native app by using switch button in react native.Please guide me how it is possible.I can't use hooks in colors file. Here is my color file:

```
const lightMode={
    ........
    TextColor1: '#FFFFFF',
    buttonColor1: '#FFFFFF',
    borderColor1: '#3CB3FF',
    ........
}
const DarkMode={
    ........
    TextColor1: '#424242',
    buttonColor1: '#3CB3FF',
    borderColor1: '#3CB3FF',
    ........
}

let theme = 'light'
let colors = theme == 'light' ? { ...lightMode} : { ...DarkMode}
```

How to change above theme by using switch

How to enable dark mode in react native by using your own colors.

Comment: Have you tried react native paper? https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/theming.html

Comment: Similar question answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75083541/6253110

Answer (score 1):

I have ever implemented dark theme. ***But I don't add button to enable dark mode, but it would automatically change basis on phone appearance.***

So for implementing dark mode, I used `[useColorScheme]` .

The useColorScheme React hook provides and subscribes to color scheme updates from the Appearance module.
So, we can get the current theme is light or dark.

**Here is code example:**

*In your color file*: (Maybe, I will define it as theme.js)

```
theme.js

export const Theme = {
   light: {
     ........
     TextColor1: '#FFFFFF',
     buttonColor1: '#FFFFFF',
     borderColor1: '#3CB3FF',
     ........       
   },
   dark: {
     ........
     TextColor1: '#424242',
     buttonColor1: '#3CB3FF',
     borderColor1: '#3CB3FF',
     ........
   },
}
```

In your screens:

```
home.js

import {useColorScheme} from 'react-native';
import {Theme} from './theme';

export const HomeScreen = ({}) = > {
   const colorTheme = useColorScheme();
   const theme = Theme[colorTheme];
   ...       
   return (
     <View>
       <Text style={theme.TextColor1}> Hello World! </Text>
       <Button color={theme.buttonColor1}> Click </Button>
     </View>
   );
}
```

**I hope this help you solve the problem.**

Answer (score 0):

You can design a custom hook according your requirement:

```
const { useState } = require("react");
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native';

export const useTheme = () => {

    // manage theme 
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');
    // get the details of mobile theme
    const colorTheme = useColorScheme();
    
    const lightMode = {
        TextColor1: '#000',
        buttonColor1: '#fafafa',
        borderColor1: '#3CB3FF',
    }
    const DarkMode = {
        TextColor1: '#fff',
        buttonColor1: '#000',
        borderColor1: '#3CB3FF',
    }

    // change the color theme if you don't want use mobile them 
you can use simply useState variable theme a create above the code . 
      
    let colors = colorTheme == 'light' ? { ...lightMode } : { ...DarkMode }

    // handle theme according user 
    const _changeColorHandler = () => {
        if (theme == 'light') {
            setTheme('dark')
        } else {
            setTheme('light')
        }
    }
    return { colors, _changeColorHandler }
}
```

I hope this help you solve the problem.